# How to use one view on two different pages in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm building a site with Django 1.5.1. I have Album and Category models defined:

```
###models.py
    class Category(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Album(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='albums')
```

I've generated a menu to list automatically Categories and their related Albums with this view and template:

```
###views.py

    def index(request):
        categories = Category.objects.all()[:5]
        context = {'categories': categories}
        return render(request, 'gallery/index.html', context)

    def detail(request, album_id): 
        album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id) 
        return render(request, 'gallery/detail.html', {'album': album})

###index.html

    {% for category in categories %}
            {% with category.albums.all as albums %}
            {{ category.title }}
                {% if albums %}
                    {% for album in albums %}
                    <a href="/gallery/{{ album.id }}/">{{ album.title }}</a><br>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="blah">Biography</a>
```

I also have a view to show each album as a gallery indicates to detail.html. I want to show menu list beside each gallery so I used   `{% include "gallery/index.html" %}` tag at the begining of detail.html. But menu list doesn't show up when detail.html loads, I just see *Biography* fixed link.

Here is my question: **How should I import menu list generated in index.html in detail.html too?**

Comment: How do you call the `detail.html` template?

Comment: def detail(request, album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
    return render(request, 'gallery/detail.html', {'album': album})

Comment: Edit your question and add it so it will be read easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index.html` expects to receive `categories` variable in order to create the menu. If you want to include it in some other template you have to pass the `categories` variable to the other template for the included one. If you have some conflicts with names you can also pass variables to the `include` tag like this:

```
{% include 'include_template.html' with foo=bar%}
```

So the included template can use the variable `foo` which has the value `bar`.

For example, you need to pass the `categories` variable to the context generating for the `detail.html` like this:

```
def detail(request, album_id):
    categories = Category.objects.all()[:5] 
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id) 
    return render(request,
        'gallery/detail.html',
        {'album': album,
         'categories':categories}
    )
```

And the line that includes the `index.html` template inside the `detail.html` template should remain like it is in the question:

```
{% include "gallery/index.html" %}
```

What I just did was pass the `categories` variable needed by `index.html` for rendering the menu to the `detail.html` template, which in turn, will pass it to all included template (`index.html`).

That should get the menu working from within `detail.html` template.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I just could import Album title using this: {% include 'gallery/index.html' with categories=albums.title %} How can I import whole menu list?

Comment: `albums.title`? I'm not sure about what are you doing. See `albums` is in plural. Are you referring to a single album or just misspelled? Any ways, you need to provide the categories. That's because your `index.html` template iterates through the `categories` variable. That way you are just passing it some album's title. Is it clear?

Comment: `album` is the only variable you're passing to the `detail.html` template. You need to provide `categories` as well for the included `index.html` template work

Comment: I'm confused. I don't get what shod I replace instead of foo=bar in include tag. And is that enough? Should I change views too?

Comment: I'll now add some code to the `views.py` to show how it may work. For now, forget about the `with foo=bar` part.